# Extending C drive not possible

Tags: windows, partitioning

This is my computer partition list.

[image: Explorer View]

You can see my C drive is running very low on disk space. I wanted to extend my disk space, so I used mmc Disk managment to shrink a volume, but I can't extend it to the C drive because the extended volume in dropdown list of C is not clickable.

I've tried many packages, but none were able to do it.  My C drive is simple, basic, NTFS, healthy (boot, crash dump, primary partition).

The MMC Windows:

[image: MMC Window]

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

In order to extend the C drive, you will need to have contiguous space for it to expand into

from the looks of your second screenshot, the available space immediately after C is taken up by a extended partition with three logical partitions in it

If the free space AFTER this volume is what you intended to extend C into, you will need to use a partition management tool to move the logical volume to that empty part of the disk, so that the C drive can expand into the free space.  You will also need to remove the currently formatted partition (it still looks to be formatted as an NTFS partition, albeit without a drive letter)

Could you go into a bit more detail as to what you are envisioning?

something like [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) or [Easeus](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/) would help move things around a bit, but i would advice some familiarity with them before messing with your partition tables

Have you considered getting a second drive and cloning the data out to it?

Comment: what about merging c and d

Comment: Unfortunately, because D is part of a logical drive, removing it wouldn't make any space available for C, because the logical drive will still exist, even if the partition does not, and to get rid of the logical drive you would need to remove all the partitions in it, or resize/move it with a partition manager, same situation as above

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do this using the MMC Disk Management snapin, because you have already used the space directly after your 'C' partition for your 'D' partition.

If you're able to create a partition with sufficient space elsewhere, you could copy the content of the 'D' partition into that, then delete the 'D' partition, which would allow you to extend the 'C' partition onto the newly-created free space.

Answer (score -1):

Boot g parted copy data  from logical  D-drive to any other partition then delete d-drive logical partition.
Reduce the size of extended logical as free space will be left .
Now increase the size of C-drive.

Comment: This seems to be saying essentially the same thing as the oldest and highest-voted answer, but much less clearly.